# Plotting multiple series ggplot2 line_geom

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and I'm conscious that this is fairly basic question from a hopeless newbie. I've been attempting to find a solution using others questions/approaches for the past couple of days, but am yet to crack it. I would really appreciate some guidance.

I have a [data frame with 5 columns and 47 rows](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6tyyFIqeUBqT2loOUlHcFhFcm8/edit?usp=sharing) which I am trying to chart using geom_line in ggplot2. The first column of my data frame is an 'age' variable which I want on the x-axis. The other four variables are numbers (currency). I'm looking to have those four variables as separate series.

I've gathered from tutorials/other questions that I may need to melt the data for this to work.

My current code is pasted below. This currently prints a figure with no data. When I print the e$value, but I call call the data I get a NULL response. Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
options(na.action = "na.omit")
RAW <- read.csv("~/Google Drive/RAW2.csv")
RAW.e <- melt(RAW, measure.vars=c("NO", "HS", "VE", "DE"))
x="RAW.e$AGE"
y="RAW.e$value"
RAW.p <- ggplot(RAW.e, aes(x=x, y=y, color=variable))+
geom_line()
RAW.p
```

Comment: The reason this fails is that you are setting x and y to character strings. If you used `x <- RAW.e$Age; y <- RAW.e$value` it would work, but @Didzis' solution is *much* better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ggplot()` you can reference your columns directly in the `aes()` call.

```
ggplot(RAW.e, aes(x=AGE, y=value, color=variable))+ geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! Much appreciated. I see where I went wrong here.